# Multiple SCNMaterials with shared shader

Tags: shader, scenekit

One of the most basic techniques for rendering is to apply the same vertex/fragment shader to multiple objects, which may use different textures. However, I don't understand how this is done in SceneKit.

It seems to me that if you want to use two different textures in two different polygons, you need to create two separate SCNMaterial objects, and apply them to those polygons (or, more precisely, to the SCNGeometry objects that contain those polygons).

However, if you create two SCNMaterial instances, each will have its own independent vertex and fragment shader sources, which will be compiled and used separately. This especially if you want to modify those shaders in some manner.

This means that if I have a thousand polygons, each with its own differing texture, then there will be a thousand copies of the same vertex/fragment shaders applied to them, rather than the one and same shader instances being shared among them. Even though the shaders do the exact same thing. This is ridiculously inefficient. (Imagine if you were to create a 2D sprite-based engine like this, for example. Every single sprite would have its own separate copy of the same default shader, rather than sharing the same shader object, making it really inefficient.)

I can't figure out a way to have two SCNMaterial objects, with different textures, share the same shader objects. Or to do this in any other way within SceneKit, for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

SceneKit will automatically detect that these materials can share the same vertex and fragment shaders and won't compile them twice.

Comment: You mean that it compares the shader source codes of SCNMaterial objects, and automatically merges them to be shared whenever they are identical?